# Reward is converging but actions are not correct in reinforcement learning

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, policy

I am developing a reinforcement learning agent.

My reward structure looks like

```
thermal_coefficient = -0.1

        zone_temperature = output[6]

        if zone_temperature < self.temp_sp_min:
            temp_penalty = self.temp_sp_min - zone_temperature
        elif zone_temperature > self.temp_sp_max:
            temp_penalty = zone_temperature - self.temp_sp_max
        else :
            temp_penalty = 0
```

my `temp_sp_min` is 23.7 and `temp_sp_max` is 24.5. When i train the agent based on epsilon greedy action selection strategy, after around 10000 episodes my rewards are converging, When I test the trained agent now, the actions taken by the agent doesn't make sense, meaning when `zone_temperature` is less than `temp_sp_min` it is taking an action, which further reduces zone_temperature.

I don't understand where am I going wrong. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that epsilon-greedy algorithm takes action that are not logical, indeed those actions are supposed to be exploration (actions taken with probability 1-epsilon).

But i think for your problem it's an algorithm for contextual MAB that you need, because your reward depends on a context/state (current temperature). Try other algorithm that performs better in such conditions as LinUCB or DQN.

Comment: Hi I am using DQN for training the agent. The problem is agent is taking wrong actions during testing phase. I understand that during training, it can explore and take some illogical actions. But during the test phase, once the agent is trained, it should always take logical actions right?

Comment: it's ok if the frequency of  "illogical" actions decreases over time. And overall those kind of questions depends a lot of the model and how you evaluate it. per example for Epsilon-greedy you can stop the exploration at certain time by putting epsilon = 0 and begin a full exploitation strategy.

Comment: Hi @Jad !! Thanks for the response. I don't understand why the frequency of illogical actions will decrease over time in testing phase, In testing it just takes the action, from a particular state based on the learning it had during training. so, once it has learnt, why will the frequency reduce ?